# Targeting lists in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a ul with the class .answers.

How can I target the last li in that list?

I've got:

```
$(this).parent().children(".answers li:last")
```

This targets the answers ul fine:

```
$(this).parent().children(".answers');
```

Just having trouble with the last bit

---

HTML

```
<div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Answers:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                    <ul class="answers">
                        <li class="answer">
                            <input class="input-xxlarge answerInput"  type="text" placeholder="Answer A" name="answer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse deleteAnswerBtn">x</button>
                        </li>
                        <li class="answer">
                            <input class="input-xxlarge answerInput"  type="text" placeholder="Answer A" name="answer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse deleteAnswerBtn">x</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <button type="button" class="btn addAnswerBtn">+</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
$(this).parent().find('ul.answers li:last');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5qbZj/3/)**

Comment: Works fine actually: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5qbZj/. You need to post your HTML and expand your question.

Comment: Your example does not take in to account the parent selector as stated in my original question.

Comment: The parent selector of what? Is there some requirement to use the parent selector? Post your HTML.

Comment: HTML posted, the code runs when the button is pressed, trying to get the last li element.

Comment: Which button, the one with the plus sign? And do you want the last list item element, or the value in the input in the last list item?

Comment: Just the li. You fiddle still is not what I require, I need to use parent, I can't just select based on class, there will be multiple + buttons on the page, each needing to get their local lists

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [last-selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) for that case:

```
$('ul.answers').find('li:last')
```